# Exponents in Genetic Programming

Tags: genetic-programming, exponent

I want to have real-valued exponents (not just integers) for the terminal variables. 
For example, lets say I want to evolve a function y = x^3.5 + x^2.2 + 6. How should I proceed? I haven't seen any GP implementations which can do this.
I tried using the power function, but sometimes the initial solutions have so many exponents that the evaluated value exceeds 'double' bounds!
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you doing this in? Could you possibly make your question a bit more explicit/specific?

Comment: I am using C for symbolic regression. May be I wasn't clear. In my current implementation the only way I can get exponents for the variables is through the '*' function. So if I have a tree like (*(*x x) x), I get x^3. But how do I proceed if I want to evolve x^3.5 as part of my regression function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEAP](http://deap.googlecode.com) (in Python) implements it. In fact there is an [example](http://code.google.com/p/deap/source/browse/examples/gp_symbreg.py) for that. By adding the math.pow from Python in the primitive set you can acheive what you want.

```
pset.addPrimitive(math.pow, 2)
```

But using the pow operator you risk getting something like x^(x^(x^(x))), which is probably not desired. You shall add a restriction (by a mean that I not sure) on where in your tree the pow is allowed (just before a leaf or something like that).

[OpenBeagle](http://beagle.sourceforge.net/) (in C++) also allows it but you will need to develop your own primitive using the pow from `<math.h>`, you can use as an example the Sin or Cos primitive.

Comment: Nested pow is exactly the problem I am facing. I can restrict the pow operator to just before the leaf node. But I also want that exponent to be a constant, not one of the variables, as @Tom Castle suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If only *some* of the initial population are suffering from the overflow problem then just penalise them with a poor fitness score and they will probably be removed from the population within a few generations.

But, if the problem is that virtually all individuals suffer from this problem, then you will have to add some constraints. The simplest thing to do would be to constrain the exponent child of the power function to be a real literal - which would mean powers would not be allowed to be nested. It depends on whether this is sufficient for your needs though. There are a few ways to add constraints like these (or more complex ones) - try looking in to Constrained Syntactic Structures and grammar guided GP.

A few other simple thoughts: can you use a data-type with a larger range? Also, you could reduce the maximum depth parameter, so that there will be less room for nested exponents. Of course that's only possible to an extent, and it depends on the complexity of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Integers have a different binary representation than reals, so you have to use a slightly different bitstring representation and recombination/mutation operator.

For an excellent demonstration, see slide 24 of www.cs.vu.nl/~gusz/ecbook/slides/Genetic_Algorithms.ppt or check out the Eiben/Smith book "Introduction to Evolutionary Computing Genetic Algorithms." This describes how to map a bit string to a real number. You can then create a representation where x only lies within an interval [y,z]. In this case, choose y and z to be the of less magnitude than the capacity of the data type you are using (e.g. 10^308 for a double) so you don't run into the overflow issue you describe.

Comment: I am using C for symbolic regression. May be I wasn't clear. In my current implementation the only way I can get exponents for the variables is through the '*' function. So if I have a tree like (*(*x x) x), I get x^3. But how do I proceed if I want to evolve x^3.5 as part of my regression function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that with real-valued exponents and a negative base you will not obtain a real, but a complex number. For example, the [Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) implementation in .NET says that you get NaN if you attempt to calculate the power of a negative base to a non-integer exponent. You have to make sure all your x values are positive. I think that's the problem that you're seeing when you "exceed double bounds".

Btw, you can try the [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com) GP implementation. It is very flexible with a configurable grammar.

Comment: This is a good point. The implementation of the power function that you are using needs to be protected from this situation, so any possible inputs have a valid return value.